# Geant4, simulate photon emitted into lead

Tags: computational-physics, simulation, software

I have just learned [Geant4](https://geant4.web.cern.ch/) and recently I tried to simulate photons emitted into lead. After I collected the data and figured out the transmission of photons. I found my data is bigger than the transmission data from XCOM.

Here's my PhysicsLists

```
void PhysicsList::ConstructParticle()
{

  G4BosonConstructor  pBosonConstructor;
  pBosonConstructor.ConstructParticle();

  G4LeptonConstructor pLeptonConstructor;
  pLeptonConstructor.ConstructParticle();

  G4MesonConstructor pMesonConstructor;
  pMesonConstructor.ConstructParticle();

  G4BaryonConstructor pBaryonConstructor;
  pBaryonConstructor.ConstructParticle();

  G4IonConstructor pIonConstructor;
  pIonConstructor.ConstructParticle();

  G4ShortLivedConstructor sLivedConstructor;
  sLivedConstructor.ConstructParticle();
  
}


#include "G4PhysicsListHelper.hh"

#include "G4ComptonScattering.hh"
#include "G4GammaConversion.hh"
#include "G4PhotoElectricEffect.hh"

#include "G4eMultipleScattering.hh"

#include "G4eIonisation.hh"
#include "G4eBremsstrahlung.hh"
#include "G4eplusAnnihilation.hh"

void PhysicsList::ConstructProcess()
{
  AddTransportation();
  G4PhysicsListHelper* ph = G4PhysicsListHelper::GetPhysicsListHelper();
  
  auto particleIterator=GetParticleIterator();
  particleIterator->reset();
  while( (*particleIterator)() ){
    G4ParticleDefinition* particle = particleIterator->value();
    G4String particleName = particle->GetParticleName();
     
    if (particleName == "gamma") {
          
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4RayleighScattering, particle);      
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4PhotoElectricEffect, particle);
      G4ComptonScattering* cs   = new G4ComptonScattering;
      cs->SetEmModel(new G4KleinNishinaModel());
      ph->RegisterProcess(cs, particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4GammaConversion, particle);
      
    } else if (particleName == "e-") {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eMultipleScattering, particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eIonisation,         particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eBremsstrahlung,     particle);      

    } else if (particleName == "e+") {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eMultipleScattering, particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eIonisation,         particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eBremsstrahlung,     particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4eplusAnnihilation,   particle);  

    } else if (particleName == "mu+" || 
               particleName == "mu-"    ) {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4MuMultipleScattering(), particle); 
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4MuIonisation(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4MuBremsstrahlung(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4MuPairProduction(), particle);
                   
    } else if( particleName == "proton" ||
               particleName == "pi-" ||
               particleName == "pi+"    ) {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hMultipleScattering(), particle);      
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hIonisation(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hBremsstrahlung(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hPairProduction(), particle);            
     
    } else if( particleName == "alpha" || 
               particleName == "He3"    ) {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hMultipleScattering(), particle);           
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4ionIonisation(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4NuclearStopping(), particle);      
            
    } else if( particleName == "GenericIon" ) {

      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hMultipleScattering(), particle);          
      G4ionIonisation* ionIoni = new G4ionIonisation();
      ionIoni->SetEmModel(new G4IonParametrisedLossModel());
      ph->RegisterProcess(ionIoni, particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4NuclearStopping(), particle);                   
      
    } else if ((!particle->IsShortLived()) &&
               (particle->GetPDGCharge() != 0.0) && 
               (particle->GetParticleName() != "chargedgeantino")) {
               
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hMultipleScattering(), particle);
      ph->RegisterProcess(new G4hIonisation(), particle);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the chart of my data and data from XCOM.

[image]

Did I miss any physics processes? Or is there any ways to collect transmission energy? If someone could guide me to understanding how one does determine this I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: This is a question you will need to ask the two involved projects.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth Thank you, but could you teach me what to do next? I am a beginner of stackexchange.

Comment: "I found my data is bigger than the transmission data from XCOM" Are you really just asking why your measured data is not the same as the simulation? Is there any documentation or examples for Geant4 you can start with?

Comment: @SHZ I assume that both Geant4 and XCOM will have mailing lists or user forums where this is the sort of question you should ask there. That is where everyone who knows these codes well hangs out.

Comment: @uhoh Sorry, I think my expression is not clear. I figured out these XCOM transmission data with "XCOM: Photon Cross Sections Database". [link](https://www.nist.gov/pml/xcom-photon-cross-sections-database) And I added some code in exampleB1. How do I show my code here? Thank you.

Comment: @SHZ I'm not sure how to reply, what is "exampleB1"? Since you are already showing code here, why are you asking "How do I show my code here?"?